# Как сделать спойлер?

Tags: android

Есть ли готовые решения для спойлера?

Если нету как его сделать??

Comment: @Qwertiy, понял, простите. Коммент удалю, ответ напишу, но позже

Comment: @Flippy, комментарий вполне можно было оставить до написания ответа.

Comment: @Flippy или Qwertiy можно вернуть тот коммент, где вы описывали действия как сделать спойлер, если не получится у вас написать пример??

Comment: @Qwertiy от коммент, где вы описывали действия как сделать спойлер, если не получится у вас написать пример?? –

Comment: > Создайте кастомный `LinearLayout` и назовите его `SpoilerView`. Создайте разметку с тегом `merge` и ориентацией `vertical`. Внутри него создайте `RelativeLayout` с `TextView` - названием спойлера и `ImageView` для иконки открыто/закрыто. В `SpoilerView` делайте инфлейт созданной разметки. Там же повесьте слушатель на `RelativeLayout` и по клику открывайте/закрывайте спойлер + меняйте иконку открыто/закрыто. Также сделайте методы `collapse` и `expand` для закрытия/открытия. После всего этого используйте `SpoilerView` в XML и внутри него можете запихнуть любые `View`. Место для ответа занято.

Comment: Скопировал содержимое комментария @Flippy, восстановить комментарий, удялённый автором, я не могу.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо, не знал что так можно. попробую сделать, как сделаю тут выложу